# How to redirect cout to console in linux?

Tags: linux, redirect, console, cout

I am writing a program which is a part of another program. In the main program, they redirect the default direction of *cout* to a LOG file. For debugging of my own programm, I need to redirect the output of *cout* to console (terminal) in linux. I cannot save the console `rdbuf` like the method described in the example at:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/

Is there any way to get the handle to the console of linux in c++ for my purpose?

Comment: The answer by Chris Dodd is correct, but first make sure you aren't overcomplicating things.  The usual way to handle your problem is to split real output from debugging messages. Send the real output to `cout` and anything else to `cerr`.  That way when the output of your program is redirected, the debugging info still shows up on the terminal.  You can even redirect the standard out and standard error streams to different files: `./yourprogram 1>output.txt 2>debug.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what you mean by the 'console' and what you mean by 'redirect'.  If you're running a program in some context where its output has been redirected somewhere else, and you want to re-redirect it to the controlling terminal (what many people mean when they say 'console'), you can redirect to /dev/tty, eg:

```
program >/dev/tty
```

when you run the program.  The above might be a line in a shell script, or be a string that is passed as an argument to system(3) -- it depends on how you're starting the program.

If you want to change where the output is going within the program, you can open up a new streambuf referring to what you want, and use ios::rdbuf to redirect to it:

```
filebuf *console = new filebuf();
console->open("/dev/tty");
if (!console->is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open console" << endl;
} else {
    cout.ios::rdbuf(console);
}
```

Comment: 'console' means 'terminal' and 'redirect' means that my program is part of another program which changes the default output to a LOG file. I would like to have some outputs appeared on the terminal for debugging of my own code.

Comment: Thanks! But when I compile your suggested code, it complains that there is no matching function for call to 'rdbuf(std::fstream*&)'

Comment: The last line should read `cout.ios::rdbuf(console->rdbuf());`

Comment: Thanks! Now the code can be compiled, but it doesn't redirect the `cout << "some test text" << endl` neither to LOG file nor to console (terminal)!

Comment: Depending on what version of C++ your compiler supports, you might need `cout.set_rdbuf` or `cout.ios::rdbuf` instead of `cout.rdbuf`

Comment: `cout.set_rdbuf` is not compatible with the compiler I use. And `cout.ios::rdbuf` didn't change the situation; no output neither to the LOG file not to the console.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to compile Chris example.
I got that "->open" was not declared in "console->open".
I'm using kdevelop 4.5.2 to compile it and what worked is the piece of code

```
ofstream console("/dev/tty"); //create stream
cout.rdbuf(console.rdbuf()); //redirects cout to the new stream
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout` goes to `stdout`, which is file descriptor 1, by definition.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. Would you please give an example code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? `cout` already goes to the console, by default, so I'm not sure.