# stdout is missing?

Tags: c++, console, stdout, cout

In the project, I have a problem about stdout;

The source coded in c/c++

Embedded project CPU : mpc 8377E

At the start the program runs correctly, but for a time running or even only some times run the program, problem causes that the console don't display ANY message!

The program runs correctly. only not any information output! but, telnet the board and echo "hello world" > /dev/ttyS0 , see "hello world" message in the console(secure CRT).

I use `cout << xxx << endl;` to display some information!

How may I to solve the problem or can you give some advice?

Comment: "The source coded in c/c++" No, the source code is in C++. I'm pretty sure `cout` isn't part of the C-standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be a problem with stdout buffering, especially if you do lots of output and it shows up eventually, in chunks.

If you write some output then exit, does the output show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to redirect cout on tty: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690388/how-to-redirect-cout-to-console-in-linux) other answer shows howt can be done either when launching the program or modifying the code.