# Opening a console from app

Tags: c++, c, linux, console

I am working on a C and C++ app that uses some graphical engine to handle gtk windows (Opencv/highgui). This app does some minor output to stdout/cout.

On Windows, starting this kind of app from the desktop automatically opens a console, showing the user what is been written on standard output, either with "printf()" or "std::cout".

On Linux, if I start it from a previously opened console, no trouble. But if I start it through the desktop (double-click), then linux doesn't open an associated console, and data written on stdout/cout is lost.
Seems that this is the normal behaviour on Linux (?).

I would like to automatically open a console from my app, when compiled on a linux platform.

This seems like a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690388/), the point is, it doesn't work! I have at present the following code:

```
#ifndef __WIN32
   filebuf* console = new filebuf();
   console->open( "/dev/tty", ios::out );
   if( !console->is_open() )
       cerr << "Can't open console" << endl;
   else
       cout.ios::rdbuf(console);
#endif
```

(cerr is redirected in a file using freopen() )

I keep getting "Can't open console". I tried replacing the console name:

```
console->open( "/dev/console", ios::out );
```

but that didn't change.

Am I in the right direction? What can I try next? Should I try to open specifically the terminal application (xterm)? But then, how could I "connect" that console with my app?

Comment: Hmm.. I know that in certain desktop environments (GNOME at least) you can create a launcher ("Shortcut" in Windows terms) on the desktop, and specify that the application launched from it is to be run with an associated terminal. If you want to try, create a new launcher and then inspect the properties of it - you will find the option there. Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: @kebs if you run your app in a terminal under a graphical environment (like gnome terminal), you will be able both to see output to the terminal and windows the app open.

Comment: @fullhack: Yes, I know that, but it is not an option in this case.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Sure, but the question was specifically about having the terminal when _not_ starting the app from a terminal.

Comment: my opinion is that an application that gives meaningful info through the terminal, must be executed from the terminal...

Comment: @ShinTakezou: I don't want to get into some philosophical argument, but IMHO, standard output is standard output, and the way the program behaves about it should not depend on how it is launched. Do you think it's up to the user to know if the app he gets needs to be launched through a terminal or through the GUI to produce the expected output? I don't.

Comment: @kebs yes it is up to the user: who has no idea about what "wget" is (just to mention one), will try to execute it from a GUI, but it is meaningless and programmers have not done any effort to cope with different behaviors of different systems when "console IO" is done but no console/terminal exists; or, rather, it is up to the programmer not to mix GUI/console that way, if both are meaningful: open a window with a "text widget" and write to it, so your app will be "full GUI".

Comment: @ShinTakezou I understand your wget example, but this is only a CL app, I'm talking about GUI apps. Let's put it differently: Windows gives the programmer the "comfort" of opening automatically a console that he can use easily to output data. I just want to mimic this, as I consider that my job is not to add a console manager to my app, I just want to use the "system" console. (although I know that this concept is kinda vague on Linux). Seems that this is as complicated as having Windows NOT opening one ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Very simple solution you might not like: have a script that runs your application in a terminal using `gnome-terminal -x <your_program> <your_args>`. Double-clicking the script will open the terminal.

**Solution 2**

A bit more involved solution add a '--noconsole' argument to your application. If the argument is present, just run your application. If '--noconsole' is not present:

```
if( fork() == 0 ) {
    execlp("gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "-x", argv[0], "--noconsole", NULL );
} else {
    exit( 0 );
}
```

This creates a child process in which it runs the application in `gnome-terminal` using the `--noconsole` arugment. Makes sense? A bit hacky, but hey, it works.

**Solution 3**

This one is the trickiest solution, but in some ways more elegant. The idea is to redirect our stdout to a file and create a terminal running `tail -f <file_name> --pid=<parent_pid>`. This prints the output of the parent process and terminates when the parent dies.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Create terminal and redirect output to it, returns 0 on success,
// -1 otherwise.
int make_terminal() {
    char  pidarg[256]; // the '--pid=' argument of tail
    pid_t child;       // the pid of the child proc
    pid_t parent;      // the pid of the parent proc
    FILE* fp;          // file to which output is redirected
    int   fn;          // file no of fp

    // Open file for redirection
    fp = fopen("/tmp/asdf.log","w");
    fn = fileno(fp);

    // Get pid of current process and create string with argument for tail
    parent = getpid();
    sprintf( pidarg, "--pid=%d", parent );

    // Create child process
    child = fork(); 
    if( child == 0 ) {
        // CHILD PROCESS

        // Replace child process with a gnome-terminal running:
        //      tail -f /tmp/asdf.log --pid=<parent_pid>
        // This prints the lines outputed in asdf.log and exits when
        // the parent process dies.
        execlp( "gnome-terminal", "gnome-terminal", "-x", "tail","-f","/tmp/asdf.log", pidarg, NULL );

        // if there's an error, print out the message and exit
        perror("execlp()");
        exit( -1 );
    } else {
        // PARENT PROCESS
        close(1);      // close stdout
        int ok = dup2( fn, 1 ); // replace stdout with the file

        if( ok != 1 ) {
            perror("dup2()");
            return -1;
        }

        // Make stdout flush on newline, doesn't happen by default
        // since stdout is actually a file at this point.
        setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, BUFSIZ );
    }

    return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Attempt to create terminal.
    if( make_terminal() != 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not create terminal!\n" );
        return -1;
    } 

    // Stuff is now printed to terminal, let's print a message every
    // second for 10 seconds.
    int i = 0;
    while( i < 10 ) {
        printf( "iteration %d\n", ++ i );
        sleep( 1 );
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that long answer, interesting, I'll try that out and comment back.

Comment: solution 1 is not much different from what suggested @fulhack (creating a .desktop shortcut for gnome or equivalent for other desktops). Your solution might be more portable, except that I'm not sure that 'gnome-terminal' is available on all platforms. Solution 2 is nice, I just tried it, and everything is included in the app, but again, needs 'gnome-terminal'. Maybe there is some generic terminal that is guaranteed to be available on _all_ linux platforms? Solution 3 will be tried tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, third solution if fine too, actually not much different from sol. 2. I tend to prefer the latter, and I think xterm is more common as terminal than gnome-terminal (on KDE systems, for example). Thanks for taking the time for a real complete answer ;-)

Comment: There's no terminal that's guaranteed to be available on any linux distro, after all there's people running linux without a GUI, but yes, xterm is a much better choice. I actually had no idea how to do this when I started, but I learned quite a bit on how file descriptors work - this is why love answering stuff of stackoverflow, the amount you learn is totally worth the time.

Comment: Also, if you've decided on Solution 2, you should note that you may need to pass the arguments to your application when restarting it with gnome-terminal, you should use [execvp](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execvp.htm) instead of execlp which takes a `char *argv[]`  argument instead of the variadic ones (note that you will have to reallocate argv[], unfortunately, to be able to add '--noconsole').

Answer (score 3):

Your examples all "open" a console - in the sense that one opens a file. This doesn't do anything to a gui. If you want to do that you will have to open a gtk window and direct the output to it.

Comment: Okay, so I assume you suggest to start a terminal, that was my second idea. But how can I "connect" this terminal to the stdout of my app ?